# Visual basic, Vissual c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Aqui molestando con un problema que no puedo solucionar.

Tengo un proyecto en Visual Basic y dentro de ese proyecto agregue otro proyecto pero de C#.
Mi problema es que quiero mandar a llamar una pagina del proyecto que esta Visual Basic a otra pagina del proyecto que esta en C#.
Hasta ahora no he podido me sale que es incorrecta la url

El proyecto en visual basic se llama QEP2 Y dentro de el esta una pagina que se llama QuickReference.aspx y es en esta pagina donde esta el botón que al darle click ejecuta el codigo que pongo abajo.

Este es el código que estoy ejecutando desde el evento click de un boton en visual basic

```
 Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Response.Redirect(String.Format("~/Formato/Default.aspx"))
        


    End Sub
```

El proyecto en C# se llama Formato y dentro hay una pagina que se llama Default.aspx esta es la pagina a la que quiero mandar a llamar desde el proyecto de Visual Basic. Mas que nada no se si esta bien la forma en que estoy armando la url en el boton.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida..

Y este es el error que me dice que no se encontro la ruta
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos

Comment: Son dos proyectos diferentes.. son dos programas diferentes.. tu pagina no esta donde vos pensas que esta.. esta en otro url... no se porque hiciste esto, pero deberias ordenarlo....

Comment: Hola, si asi es, se hizo asi porque la version de visual basic es antigua y no permite agregar nuevos cambios. Pero como es un aplicacion importante no se puede hacer el cambio por el  momento. Por eso se agrego un proyecto en c# para hacer el cambio sobre el y no afectar al de visual basic.. Entonces se puede llamar la pagina desde el boton que esta en la pagina de Visual basic?  Saludos!!

Comment: si, pero son proyectos distintos.. vas a hacer un redirect a OTRA PAGINA, eso se entiende? es como que hicieras un redirect a google.. no tienen nada que ver una con la otra...

Comment: Ok ok, pero entonces esta bien la forma en que hago el response.redirect? porque no encuentra la ruta del otro proyecto..

Comment: no. Esa otra pagina hay que levantarla en otro IIS (o el mismo) pero va a tener otra url... no es una ruta del proyecto.. es otra pagina...

Comment: Y no tengo ni idea de como decirte como hacerlo, porque deberias levantarlo primero...

Comment: Noe, piensa que estás trabajando para `mitsubishi.com` y quieres redirigir al usuario a la lista de autos en `tesla.com/modelos`. Dentro del proyecto de mitsubishi no haces el redirect así: `~/modelos`, porque si estás dentro de la solución de mitsubishi, el router de esa solución piensa que estás llamando a `mitsubishi.com/modelos`, porque es **el mismo proyecto**. el redirect es hacia `https://www.tesla.com/modelos`. ENTONCES, gbianchi te dice que tendrás dos proyectos corriendo uno al lado de otro, con urls diferentes. El redirect, a como lo tienes, no funciona.

Comment: El redirect debe ser: `Response.Redirect(String.Format("localhost:6666/Formato/Default.aspx"))`, o el url que el proyecto C# tenga. Por cierto... Por qué utilizas `String.Format()`? No está dando ningún formato. Comillas simples y ya. No te compliques

Comment: Siendo dos proyectos distintos, ¿se pretende que estén los dos proyectos activos al mismo tiempo, es decir puedo entrar al sitio web en vb que tiene la versión 1 y a su vez también es posible consultar al versión 2 desde el sitio web que se construyo con c#?, de eso depende la respuesta. De las dos formas se podría, por cierto.